# Error -3 in extracting from zip file using unzip

Tags: r, rstudio, unzip, zip

**Hello world** (*seems appropriate for the first question ever asked here*),

What I need to do is to read a date of creation/modification of a certain file inside of the zipped folder.

When I use code:

```
file.mtime(unzip(zipfile, files, setTimes = T))
```

there is a warning saying:

> error -3 in extracting from zip file

What appears is that this file is empty (0 kb). While it doesn't affect my code and running speed right now it would be nice in the long run if someone could give me a understanding what is an "error -3", how to make that this warning disappear or at least to give me a clue where to look to resolve this problem.

Comment: R's `dounzip.c` uses and/or passes through some numerical error codes from zlib. Looking at `zlib.h` reveals that error code -3 is `Z_DATA_ERROR`, which the [docs](http://www.zlib.net/zlib_how.html) just describe as meaning _the deflate data is invalid or incomplete_. I don't have any more insight than that.

Comment: What if you unzip outside R? Does that work? I guess it does not...